# The code is used to add the digits in a digital clock to each other. I duplicated code and could use some help DRYing it out

Tags: ruby

I'm using [Codefights](http://codefights.com) to improve my skills. This challenge is to change the number submitted as total minutes into the digital read out on a clock i.e. `hh:mm` and then add all the numbers to together. So `h` + `h` + `m` + `m`.

My code works and I've passed all the tests, but it duplicates the same process for variables I've named `number` and `float`. What are some ways I can clean this up? At the bottom of the code I put the tests with the correct answers commented out next to them.

```
def lateRide(n)
  n = n.to_f
  n = n/60
  float = n % 1
  number = n - float
  number = number.to_i

  float = float * 60
  float = float.round.to_i

  if number > 9
    tens = number/10
    ones = number-(tens*10)
  else
    tens = 0
    ones = number
  end

  if float > 9
    ftens = float/10
    fones = float-(ftens*10)
  else
    ftens = 0
    fones = float
  end
  tens + ones + ftens + fones
end

puts lateRide(240) #4
puts lateRide(808) #14
puts lateRide(1439) #19
puts lateRide(0) #0
puts lateRide(23) #5
puts lateRide(8) #8
```

Comment: Please change the title to a brief summary of the purpose of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current code:

- Don't name variables `float` and `number`; name then for what they *represent*, not their datatype.
- Don't use `camelCase` for methods; Ruby convention is to use `snake_case`

As for its functionality: There's a much easier way to get hours and minutes from a total number of minutes:

```
hours, minutes = total.divmod(60)
```

`#divmod` is basically a convenient shorthand for "quotient and remainder"; it's the same as this:

```
hours = (total / 60).floor
minutes = total % 60
```

just in one method.

Now, `#divmod` returns an array with 2 numbers in it, and in the code above I simply assign those two numbers to `hours` and `minutes` respectively.

If you then use `#divmod` again on those two but with `10` as the argument, you can get the "ones" and the "tens", the same way you just got "minutes" and "hours" by using `60` as your argument.

So say the total number of minutes is 119, i.e. 1h 59m, and you want to split both the hours and minutes, you can do this:

```
total
  .divmod(60)                    #=> [1, 59]
  .flat_map { |n| n.divmod(10) } #=> [0, 1, 5, 9]
```

Note however, that if you've got more than 99 hours, you could run into problems, as you'll only get the ones and tens; not the hundreds. E.g. 6000 minutes is 100 hours, but the above would return `[10, 0, 0, 0]` (sum 10), rather than *all* the individual digits, which would be `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` (sum 1).

This *might* be correct for the challenge still, since the readout is `hh:mm`, and thus doesn't say anything one way or the other about how 3-or-more hour-digits should be handled. The "digital sum" might be 10 or 1 - or zero if anything above 4 digits is just ignored. Or it could be `d:hh:mm`, and it'd be 4 days + 4 hours + 0 minutes = 8... there are just a lot of unknowns.

But if we assume that the input will stick to 2-digit hours, the code above will work without any ambiguity - all we need is the sum. For that you can use `#reduce` (aka `#inject`):

```
def late_ride(minutes)
  minutes
    .divmod(60)
    .flat_map { |n| n.divmod(10) }
    .reduce(:+)
end
```

and bingo.

But if the idea instead is to add up *all* the digits individually *and* the hours can have 3 or more digits, this, as mentioned, won't be quite right.

You can use `#divmod` repeatedly or recursively to get the digits of an arbitrary number of hours, but for this little challenge, I'll just suggest something I usually don't suggest: Convert the digital readout to a string, and get the digits that way. I usually try to avoid this, since it seems inelegant to treat a numeric value as a string only to get another numeric value. Just hey, it works, so:

```
total
  .divmod(60)  #=> [1, 59]
  .join        #=> "159"
  .chars       #=> ["1", "5", "9"]
```

From here, you can use `#reduce` again to get the sum (just call `to_i` to get actual numbers from the strings). And then this is your method:

```
def late_ride(minutes)
  minutes
    .divmod(60)
    .join
    .chars
    .reduce(0) { |sum, n| sum + n.to_i }
end
```

or, written another way:

```
def late_ride(minutes)
  minutes
    .divmod(60)
    .join
    .chars
    .map(&:to_i)
    .reduce(:+)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This exactly the sort of response I was hoping to get. I knew there must be a much simpler way to do what I was doing. I did know about the convention to use snake_case, that was just a hold over from the Codefights problem(cut&paste). I knew a few of the methods, but I'd never seen .divmod before. The more I code the more I realize it's like Ninjutsu, knowing a method is like knowing how to punch or kick, it's putting combinations together that makes you a ninja. Thanks for the detail and helpful info.

Comment: @ReedMacConnell Well, while ninjas are cool, I'd prefer to think of it as vocabulary and expression since code is language, not a deadly fight :)  I also updated my answer with a little more discussion and a simpler method that might work too, if some assumptions hold